# Zomato and swiggy Apis availability for restaurants

Tags: zomato-api, swiggy-api

I’m developing an accounting system for a client who owns a restaurant. My goal is to replace their existing manual method with an automated solution that processes order summary data from CSV files generated by Swiggy and Zomato, utilizing an ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) process.

I’m interested in fully automating this workflow by using Swiggy and Zomato’s APIs designed for restaurant owners. While I’ve discovered [APIs tailored for customer functionalities](https://www.postman.com/api-evangelist/workspace/zomato/api/fe5cc858-a82f-4554-b764-19d86238ab44), such as restaurant browsing, I’ve been unable to find APIs that allow operations on behalf of the restaurant owner. Does anyone know if such APIs are available?